# Not getting expected function renaming files via batch script

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have a script I've written to remove the first six characters and then replace the beginning of the filename with the parent folders name. It currently seems to work, but then continues cutting 6 characters at a time till nothing is left, then adds the parent name. Don't know how I can fix this.

Files are currently named SF-1.1~~~~~~~~.pdf , SF-2.3~~~~~~~.pdf, etc and I just want to remove that SF string including the numbers. The rename command hated the period so I have the code prior to the rename removing any periods other than the extension and making them spaces.

```
set mypath=%cd%
echo %mypath% (where %mypath% is the current directory that the batch file is sitting in)
for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do set "parent=%%~nxa"
rem echo %parent%

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%cd%"

    for /r "%root%" %%a in ("*.?*.pdf") do (
        set "filename=%%~na"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
        for %%f in ("!filename:.= !") do (
            endlocal  
            ren "%%~fa" "%%~f%%~xa"
        )
    )
del root



dir /b *.pdf > temp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp) do rename "*.pdf" "//////*.pdf"
del temp


dir /b *.pdf > temp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp) do ren "%%a" "%parent% %%a"
del temp
```

Comment: I guess `dir /b *.pdf > temp`, `for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp) do rename "*.pdf" "//////*.pdf"`, `del temp` should read `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do rename "%%a" "//////*.%%~xa"`…

Comment: …and `%mypath%` is not the parent of the script, it is the current working directory (`%cd%`), which may be something different; the parent is `%~dp0.`!

Comment: What is ```del root``` supposed to do?